# экранируються кавычки при post запосе php 7

Tags: post, curl, php7

```
$Post['upload_form[file]"; filename=""'."\r\n".'Content-Type: application/octet-stream']='';
```

Если передать в curl. php < 5
экранирование не происходит
а в php 7
добавляеться слеш (

```
$Post['upload_form[file]\"; filename=\"\"'."\r\n".'Content-Type: application/octet-stream']='';
```

как от него избавиться?

Answer (score 0):

Это из-за настроек magic_quotes_gpc и/или magic_quotes_runtime, которая удалена в php 5.4. Можно попробовать настроить их в php.ini: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/security.magicquotes.disabling.php

Comment: спасибо за ответ.а как можно без настроек php.ini. хостинг этого не дает настроить